# SQL Server "FOR XML" encoding HTML entities?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am using SQL Server Management Studio. I have inherited a query that has a section that looks like:

```
...
ISNULL(
CASE
    WHEN LOWER(PersonClass.Detail) LIKE '%student%'
    THEN SUBSTRING((
            SELECT DISTINCT
                ' / '+STUDENT_TERM.DEPT_NAME
            FROM Warehouse.STUDENT_TERM STUDENT_TERM
                INNER JOIN Warehouse.TERM TERM
                    ON STUDENT_TERM.TERM_CD = TERM.TERM_CD
                    AND TERM.TERM_START_DT <= @fyEnd
                    AND ISNULL(TERM.TERM_END_DT, GETDATE()) >= @fyStart
            WHERE Persons.DWPersonId = STUDENT_TERM.DWPERSID FOR
            XML PATH('')
    ), 4, 100000)
END, '') AS StudentHome,
...
```

This is finding a student's "home department".  There is the possibility that a student could have more than one home so the above works a bit like MySQL's `group_concat`.

My question is about an unintended artifact of the query.  Several departments have names in the data warehouse that have embedded ampersands `&` in them like:

```
A & B
```

The result of the query though is "HTML encoded" turning "A & B" into "A &amp; B".

If I run the inner query the result is as expected with a simple ampersand and not the encoded form.  I am guessing that the `FOR XML` is doing the encoding.

Is there a way to do the `group_concat` without having the result encoded?

Comment: You should have a standard library in any language you are using that will convert the html entities back

Comment: Rather than `SUBSTRING` it's often better to use `STUFF` the remove characters from the start of a string.

Comment: @Larnu -- why is that?

Comment: Because, if the OP *did* have more than 10000 character's it would be truncated. `STUFF` would simply be used to replace the first characters, it wouldn't be able to truncate it, @Hogan .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value from the xml instead of cast to string:

```
ISNULL(
CASE
    WHEN LOWER(PersonClass.Detail) LIKE '%student%'
    THEN SUBSTRING((
            SELECT DISTINCT
                ' / '+STUDENT_TERM.DEPT_NAME
            FROM Warehouse.STUDENT_TERM STUDENT_TERM
                INNER JOIN Warehouse.TERM TERM
                    ON STUDENT_TERM.TERM_CD = TERM.TERM_CD
                    AND TERM.TERM_START_DT <= @fyEnd
                    AND ISNULL(TERM.TERM_END_DT, GETDATE()) >= @fyStart
            WHERE Persons.DWPersonId = STUDENT_TERM.DWPERSID FOR
            XML PATH(''),TYPE
    ).value(N'.','nvarchar(max)') , 4, 100000)
END, '') AS StudentHome,
```